# MongoDb updating old documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to MongoDb and to the NoSQL concept of storing information. Unlike in SQL Server, adding or updating a column name in a table will affect all of the records. I can assume that when I pull a record, that column will be there. It may or may not have a value depending on how it was setup.

But how would you handle a situation in MongoDb where you have an outdated document and you want to pull it and now your code is looking for a property that did not exist or was just recently renamed?

Comment: Exactly as you do with any other untrusted data sources, e.g. user input - check what data you have and either ignore invalid documents, use default values, or stop execution of the program.

Comment: I'd accept this as an answer but I can't. I thought there's some magic that mongodb does to make this easy. but I guess for a very old document that undergone numerous revisions my code will have to check every single member.

Comment: It wasn't an answer but a comment to start with. There is no magic and it's a good thing. Magic implies assumptions and hence is either unreliable or restrictive. It doesn't matter how many times your data changed. What matters is current state of your application and what data it requires to function. See my answer for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few examples of different technics.

Assuming we have a collection `pets` with documents like:

```
{
    kind: "cat",
    age: 2
}
```

and at some point we added a field "nick", so new documents look like:

```
{
    kind: "cat",
    age: 2,
    nick: "Tom"
}
```

Your app require "nick" field to list pets.

1. ### Use defaults

   Update old documents with default values (you may known it as 'ALTER TABLE' magic in SQL terms):

   ```
   db.pets.updateMany({nick: {$exists: false}}, {$set: {nick: "NONAME"}});
   ```

   If you need to support both versions you need to do it runtime.

   On application side:

   ```
   db.pets.find({}).forEach(pet => print(p.nick || "NONAME") );
   ```

   On db side:

   ```
   db.pets.aggregate([
       {$project: {
           kind: 1,
           age: 1,
           nick: { $ifNull: [ "$nick", "NONAME" ] }
       }}
   ])
   ```
2. ### Ignore invalid documents

   Remove them:

   ```
   db.pets.remove({nick: {$exists: false}})
   ```

   If you need to support both versions you need to filter them out runtime:

   ```
   db.pets.find({
       kind: {$exists: true},
       age: {$exists: true},
       nick: {$exists: true}
   );
   ```

   You can make it more defensive by specifying [type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/):

   ```
   db.pets.find({
       kind: {$type: "string"},
       age: {$type: "int"},
       nick: {$type: "string"}
   );
   ```
3. ### Stop program execution

   ```
   db.pets.find({}).forEach(pet => if(!pet.nick){throw new Error("Pet " + pet._id + " has no nick!")} );
   ```